# cpp preprocessor doesn’t recognise UTF-32 string

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am doing some compiler research work. For this code:

```
static const unsigned char *dir= U"pragma dependency";
```

`cpp4.2` on Ubuntu 14 works, whereas `cpp6` on Ubuntu 16 will throw an error. If `U` is deleted, it's OK.

So what's wrong with `cpp6`?

Updates:
I tested this code in a `C` project and there is no error. If it's in a `C++` project, it'll be the case as someone mentioned below.

Comment: You are trying to implicitly convert `char32_t*` pointer to `unsigned char *`. I don't see how it could ever compile. Any compiler that accepts this line is non-conforming (aka buggy). Also, I don't see what this has to do with preprocessor.

Comment: "Will throw an error" is not an adequate problem description. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: 4.2 is ancient, released in 2007.  Back then the U prefix meant utf16 with no decent way to store it.  I think, this is fading fast.  Oracle submitted a patch in 2008 to add char16_t and char32_t, subsequently added to C++11.

Comment: @HansPassant The code is from here [https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/403.gcc.html]. We have a old project which was developed with cpp4. Now I need to make sure it works with the latest Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything wrong with your compiler. When you prefix a string literal with `U` , it means it will be an array of  `const char32_t` , not an array of `const unsigned char`

You have to change your code to

```
 static const char32_t *dir= U"pragma dependency";
```

Comment: But when tested this code in a C project, there is no error msgs.

Comment: C is quite different than C++. You should at least get a warning if you do this in C, such as "warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type" , which suggest that at best you better know  what you are doing and at worst it's just going to blow up your program. C++ is as per ususal more strict that C, and will not let you convert between incompatible pointers.

Comment: I didn't get any warning. I used eclipse CDT. Did you test it in a C project?

Comment: Yes. You get this warning, https://ideone.com/deZuOD , You have probably not configured your eclipse project to properly show you compiler warnings, perhaps you only see the useless internal warnings from eclipse.